# How to change max sequence length for transformers.bert?

Tags: pytorch, transform, bert-language-model

I download bert-base pretrained model. I edit the config.json (from 512 to 256)

```
 "max_position_embeddings": 256,
```

Then I want to use bert model,

```
from transformers import BertForSequenceClassification
model = BertForSequenceClassification.from_pretrained(
    MODEL_PATH, 
    num_labels = 2, # The number of output labels--2 for binary classification.       
    output_attentions = False, 
    output_hidden_states = False, 
)
# Tell pytorch to run this model on the GPU.
model.cuda()
```

But it raise an error

```
Error(s) in loading state_dict for BertForSequenceClassification:
    size mismatch for bert.embeddings.position_embeddings.weight: copying a param with shape torch.Size([512, 768]) from checkpoint, the shape in current model is torch.Size([256, 768]).
```

I know the reason is because I change the max sequence length.  What is the right way, if I want to change the max seq lenght?

Answer (score 0):

The error says that the saved weights cannot be loaded to initialized model because of the difference in shapes of layers.
If you want to finetune the model on a subsequent task you can not change pretrained model config. Instead you should set max_length in [encode_plus](https://huggingface.co/transformers/internal/tokenization_utils.html?highlight=encode_plus#transformers.tokenization_utils_base.PreTrainedTokenizerBase.encode_plus) function and that will truncate the input sequence to max_length.
But if you want to pretrain model with a specific config you should initialize model with no weights or may find appropriate weights on huggingface repository.